# how to capture POP3 traffic via wireshark?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

My aim is to capture network flow of different protocols (http, https, bittorrent, skype, pop3 ..) via wireshark.
I've been able to capture flows of all protocols but POP3.
I tried to send and receive mails but nothing appear on the wireshark window when using POP filter, or TCP port 110 or 995!
How can I capture POP3 traffic with wireshark?

Comment: Strange. But are you really sure that you are using POP3 and not IMAP?

Comment: I tried also IMAP tcp port number 143 and 993 filter, also no traffic is shown
@SteffenUllrich

Comment: Why do you think there should be any such traffic at all? Which application do you use to generate this traffic?

Comment: I am sending and receiving mail on hotmail, and monitoring the traffic flow on my device, I dont see anything, how should I work to monitor mail traffic? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: If you are using the hotmail web interface then all is HTTP(s) traffic. You would need to use a mail client like Thunderbird to have POP3 or IMAP.

Comment: If I use microsoft Outlook, should it work properly? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: I think the connection between Outlook and Hotmail uses some protocol over HTTP(s) and not IMAP or POP3. Better try with another mail client.

Comment: Can you open Wireshark and do some operations such as send or sync and observe the packets generated?  That would tell you what port was been used.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the ports you use to configure Outlook to work with your Hotmail account.

Also it is encrypted SSL connection, so you can't see the traffic, since you don't have Microsoft's SSL key.

[image: http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/accountsettings.htm#screenshot-smtp-authentication]